# Reason for setting coefficients of $x$ and $x^2$ equal to zero when roots are infinite.

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

While studying coordinate geometry, I came across a topic to find the equation of asymptote of a standard hyperbola, $$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 $$ in that topic, the equation of asymptote was assumed to be $y = mx + c$, and them after some work (forming a quadratic equation having roots that gave $x$ coordinates of the point of intersection of line and hyperbola), the coefficient of $x$ squared and $x$ was set to be zero due to the fact that asymptote never intersects the curve. (So the roots of quadratic that is , the $x$ coordinates of point of intersection will tend to infinity).

I want to know the REASON behind this analogy, although I'm guessing since the sum of roots is given to be the negative of coefficient of $x$ DIVIDED by coefficient of $x$ squared (by Veita's formula), since the sum of roots tends to infinity, the denominator that is, the coefficient of x squared must tend to zero, is my assumed analogy correct? But then, why the coefficient of $x$ is set to zero?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Here's the photo of the page of book in which equation of asymptote was derived. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Via9z.jpg)

> the straight line $y = mx + c \tag 1$ meets the hyperbola in points, whose abscissae are given by the equation $\qquad x^2(b^2 - a^2m^2) - 2a^2 mcx - a^2(c^2+b^2) = 0 \tag 2$ If the straight line be an asymptote, both the roots of $(2)$ must be infinite. 
>  Hence, the coefficients of $x^2$ and $x$ in it must both be zero.

Comment: You may need to be specific about what was done.

Comment: I just edited, I've now included the pic of the process I was not able to understand clearly.

Comment: Here it might help to give us the equation of the hyperbola.

Comment: Lower on the same page it says the asymptotes are given by $$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} =0, $$ so almost certainly the equation of the hyperbola was $$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1. $$

Comment: Yes but my question is that during it's derivation why did they put coefficient of x squared and coefficient of x equal to zero?

Comment: If the roots of a quadratic equation are infinity then why coefficient of x squared and x are equal to zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is going to happen if the coefficients of $x$ and $x^2$ are not zero?

$$\qquad x^2(b^2 - a^2m^2) - 2a^2 mcx - a^2(c^2+b^2) = 0 \tag 2$$

As $x\to \infty$ the right hand side stays at $0$ while the left hand side approaches either infinity or negative infinity depending on the other parameters.

Another way to see the asymptotes is to solve$$ \frac {x^2}{a^2} - \frac {y^2}{b^2} = 1$$  for $y$

Note that $$ y=\pm (b/a)x\sqrt {1-(a/x)^2}$$ which is asymptotic to  $$ y=\pm (b/a)x $$

Comment: Okkaaay! GOT IT. Thanks !

Comment: But if we put $a$ and $b$ in $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ wouldn't it give an absurd equation of $c=0$ ?

Answer (score 0):

If you now know why the coefficient of $x^2$ is zero here's an explanation for why coefficient of $x$ is zero

asymptotes are tangents to  the hyperbolas at infinity and therefore has discriminant  equal to zero
i.e. $b^2=4ac$     in equation $ax^2 + bx +c$
      $(a =0)$
     now to satisfy this condition $b=0$